# Determine structure of the entire data

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse, janitor

Say, you have the following data:

```
data <- tibble::tribble(~Countries, ~States,   ~Continents,
                        "Country 1",      1L, "continent 1",
                        "Country 1",      2L, "continent 1",
                        "Country 1",      3L, "continent 1",
                        "Country 1",      4L, "continent 1",
                        "Country 2",      1L, "continent 1",
                        "Country 2",      2L, "continent 1",
                        "Country 2",      3L, "continent 1",
                        "Country 2",      4L, "continent 1",
                        "Country 3",      1L, "continent 1",
                        "Country 3",      2L, "continent 1",
                        "Country 3",      3L, "continent 1",
                        "Country 3",      4L, "continent 1",
                        "Country 1",      1L, "continent 2",
                        "Country 1",      2L, "continent 2",
                        "Country 1",      3L, "continent 2",
                        "Country 1",      4L, "continent 2",
                        "Country 2",      1L, "continent 2",
                        "Country 2",      2L, "continent 2",
                        "Country 2",      3L, "continent 2",
                        "Country 2",      4L, "continent 2",
                        "Country 3",      1L, "continent 2",
                        "Country 3",      2L, "continent 2",
                        "Country 3",      3L, "continent 2",
                        "Country 3",      4L, "continent 2")
```

This data could have many variables of different formats with different levels of granularity. I want to understand the structure of the data so that I can say that the highest level of data is Continent with 2 values, next level of granularity is counties with 3 values, and lowest level is states with 4 values in the above data.

1. One rough way to understand this could be to keep the variable/s with the lowest number of distinct values at left i.e. Continents and those with the highest number of distinct values i.e. States to the right of the dataset.
2. Even easier way to get our head around the messy data is to create some kind of tree chart and see least granular data at the top, continents, here and most granular data at the bottom states, here, as leaves/nodes.

As a first cut, We can use tricks like showing either of the two or more variables at first/top in cases of ties when the number of unique values are same.

If doing 2nd is difficult, how can we do atleast 1st? ...May be by **evaluating distinct values of each variable in any generic messy data and then ordering the variables**! Any other method with accompanying R code would be very helpful.

The solution to the first point would look like this:

```
data <- tibble::tribble( ~Continents,  ~Countries,   ~States,
                         "continent 1", "Country 1",   1L,
                         "continent 1", "Country 1",   2L,
                         "continent 1", "Country 1",   3L,
                         "continent 1", "Country 1",   4L,
                         "continent 1", "Country 2",   1L,
                         "continent 1", "Country 2",   2L,
                         "continent 1", "Country 2",   3L,
                         "continent 1", "Country 2",   4L,
                         "continent 1", "Country 3",   1L,
                         "continent 1", "Country 3",   2L,
                         "continent 1", "Country 3",   3L,
                         "continent 1", "Country 3",   4L,
                         "continent 2", "Country 1",   1L,
                         "continent 2", "Country 1",   2L,
                         "continent 2", "Country 1",   3L,
                         "continent 2", "Country 1",   4L,
                         "continent 2", "Country 2",   1L,
                         "continent 2", "Country 2",   2L,
                         "continent 2", "Country 2",   3L,
                         "continent 2", "Country 2",   4L,
                         "continent 2", "Country 3",   1L,
                         "continent 2", "Country 3",   2L,
                         "continent 2", "Country 3",   3L,
                         "continent 2", "Country 3",   4L)
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: Sure, I just updated the expected solution to the first bullet point above.

Comment: If I understand you correct, the first part can be solved with: ``data[order(sapply(data, function(x) length(unique(x))))]``, which gets the number of unique values of each column first, returns the order of these and changes the order of columns in ``data``. I don't really understand the desired result of the second part: Do you want 3 nodes and 2 edges connecting the 3 nodes, where the order ist just displayed by vertical alignment?

Comment: Something like this: ``plot(NULL, xlim = c(-10, 10), ylim = c(-10, 10))
rect(-2, 7, 2, 9, col = "red");
text(0, 8, "Continents");
rect(-3, 4, 3, 6, col = "blue");
text(0, 5, "Countries");
rect(-4, 1, 4, 3, col = "green");
text(0, 2, "States")``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right the below code answers your questions:

```
data[order(sapply(data, function(x) length(unique(x))))] # returns the data in the desired order

# simple function for plotting the 'tree'. 
plotTree <- function(lengths, names, space = 0.3){
  L    <- lengths[O <- order(lengths)]
  N    <- names[O]
  XMax <- max(L)
  YMax <- (length(L))
  plot(NULL, xlim = c(-XMax, XMax), ylim = c(-YMax, YMax), axes = F, xlab = "", ylab = "")
  for (i in 1:length(L)){
    rect(-L[i], YMax - 1 - i *  (space + 1), L[i], YMax - i *  (space + 1), col = i)
    text(0, YMax - 1/2 - i * (space + 1), N[i], col = if (i == 1) "white" else "black")
  }
}

# usage
plotTree(sapply(data, function(x) length(unique(x))), names(data), space = 0.3)
```

Comment: That works, except the first line should be what you suggested in earlier comment i.e. data[order(sapply(data, function(x) length(unique(x))))].

Comment: Let me see if there are some other suggestions. If not, I will go ahead and accept this answer.